# Django QuerySet for objects related through a many to many

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Product(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Store(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    menu = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'm currently trying to get a list of all products available in a specific city (eg. "New York"). Since products is related through a ManyToMany as a menu in stores I'm not 100% sure what the most optimal way of running this query would be.

I'm aware of how to dig deeper into related objects such as:

```
Store.objects.all().filter(address__city="New York")
```

But how do I get to the stores from the Product object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
ids = Store.objects.filter(address__city='New York').values_list('menu', flat=True)
result = Product.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

Comment: might be useful to include distinct() at the end of the result query if you are only looking to have each product once. See django docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Product.objects.filter(store__address__city='New York')
```

I have verified this for you.

[image]

If you want Stores from product then try `product_object.strore_set.all()`

On a side note, your model designing seems to be good `store__address__city=search` make so much sense. But you have owner like in every of model, may be that's your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To get stores in New York from a product object, try something like this.

```
class Store(models.Model):
   owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   menu = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='stores') #add related_name here to access stores for a product
   address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
```

Then you get stores for a product and filter down for New York.

```
product.stores.filter(address__city='New York')
```